# Delete row from table is confusing

Tags: matlab

I create a table like this:

```
data = table(repmat({'CI'},size(ci.offer)),ci.offer,ci.bid,...
    randi(100,size(ci.offer)),randi(100,size(ci.offer)),...
    cellstr(ci.time),repmat({'quote'},size(ci.offer)),...
    'VariableNames',{'Symbol','AskPrice','BidPrice','AskSize','BidSize',...
    'DateTime','Type'});
```

Because there is pre market data, I need to delete it. I thought that the statement `data(row, :) = [];` would do the trick. What is strange is I see the statement being executed by the `fprintf` statement,

```
[numlinesData,columns] = size(data)

foundOpen = false;
row = 1;
while(false == foundOpen)
   t = data.DateTime(row, :);
   Bid = data.BidPrice(row);
   Ask = data.AskPrice(row);
   dt = datetime(t);
   hr = hour(dt);
   mint = minute(dt);
   if hr > 14 && mint > 29
       foundOpen = true;
       fprintf('Found open %i', row);
       break;
   else
       fprintf('Deleting row %i\n', row);
       data(row, :) = [];       
   end

   row = row + 1;
end
```

but when I display the `data` I see all the rows including premarket data that were in theory deleted?

```
data(1:150,:)
```

Am I not understanding `data(row, :) = [];`  ?

Comment: From reading this code, I would expect it deletes about half the premarket return data. Is that right? The way your code is written, you should never increment row. You want to keep deleting the first row until you find a time stamp of 15:30, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep deleting the first row of your table until the row matches some criteria, you should *remove* the line:

```
row = row + 1;
```

#### Higher performance alternative:

If you're having performance problems, it's almost certainly faster if you do all the deletions at once. For example:

```
rows_to_delete = [];
...
while(false == foundOpen)
    ...
    if hr > 14 && mint > 29
      foundOpen = true;
      fprintf('Found open %i', row);
      break;
    else
      rows_to_delete(end+1) = row;
    end

    row = row + 1;
 end
 data(rows_to_delete, :) = [];
```